# Apostol's book suggests $\frac{1}{y}( [y]-y) = 1$ for y=1

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

In Apostol's Introduction to Analytic Number Theory, on page 55 there is a worked example using Euler's summation formula to show that $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ grows like $\ln(x)$.

In the use of that summation formula, there is a step which suggests $\frac{1}{y}([y]-y) = 1$ for $y=1$. This doesn't make sense to me.

Here is the summation formula:

[image]

And here is the problematic step:

[image]

I've discussed with others and it is clear that the lower limit of integration is 1, and that the sum of for $y<n\leq x$, which seems contradictory for $y=1$.

Another angle I've considered is that $[y]$ is 0 in the range $[0,1)$ where 1 is not included. Again this doesn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that in theorem 3.1 the range of the summation is $y < n \leqslant x$, and in the example it's $n \leqslant x$. To apply theorem 3.1 in the example, you can either write the sum as
$$\sum_{n \leqslant x} \frac{1}{n} = 1 + \sum_{1 < n \leqslant x} \frac{1}{n}$$
and use theorem 3.1 for the latter sum, with $\frac{1}{1}(\lfloor 1\rfloor - 1) = 0$, or you can pick $y \in (0,1)$, write the sum as
$$\sum_{y < n \leqslant x} \frac{1}{n}\,,$$
and look at
$$\lim_{y \to 1^-} \frac{1}{y}(\lfloor y\rfloor - y) = -1$$
and the analogous limit for the integrals.

I'm rather convinced that what Apostol did was the first option. Unfortunately, without making it explicit, which leads to confusion sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, they replaced $f(y)([y]-y)$ by $-1$. This is because you want your sum on LHS to run over all values $n=1$ to $n=x$. So, you want $y$ to tend towards $1$ from $-\infty$. Thus, $$\lim_{y\to 1^{-1}}\frac{[y]}y{-1}=0-1=-1$$